# Wrong number of Facebook likes via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, wordpress, graph

I'm running a Wordpress blog and using default facebook like buttons on single post templates.

```
<fb:like href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" send="false" width="80" height="20" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

The number on these buttons is displayed correctly.

I'm also saving the facebook count number to post meta data by passing the link to the Graph API:

```
'http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . get_permalink()
```

This was OK, but recently I've noticed that the like number is no longer saved to the post meta data. Though the number on the like button is displayed correctly.

In order to check why the number is no longer saved to the post meta data, I opened

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://blog.com/2011/07/04/post-name/
```

in my browser. Here's the result:

```
{
   "http://blog.com/2011/07/04/post-name/": {
      "id": "284885928194873",
      "name": "Post Name",
      "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276621_284885928194893_1295441978_s.jpg",
      "link": "http://blog.com/2011/07/04/post-name/",
      "likes": 1,
      "category": "Personal blog",
      "description": "Post Description",
      "parking": {
         "street": 0,
         "lot": 0,
         "valet": 0
      },
      "hours": {
         "mon_1_open": 0,
         "mon_1_close": 0,
         "tue_1_open": 0,
         "tue_1_close": 0,
         "wed_1_open": 0,
         "wed_1_close": 0,
         "thu_1_open": 0,
         "thu_1_close": 0,
         "fri_1_open": 0,
         "fri_1_close": 0,
         "sat_1_open": 0,
         "sat_1_close": 0,
         "sun_1_open": 0,
         "sun_1_close": 0,
         "mon_2_open": 0,
         "mon_2_close": 0,
         "tue_2_open": 0,
         "tue_2_close": 0,
         "wed_2_open": 0,
         "wed_2_close": 0,
         "thu_2_open": 0,
         "thu_2_close": 0,
         "fri_2_open": 0,
         "fri_2_close": 0,
         "sat_2_open": 0,
         "sat_2_close": 0,
         "sun_2_open": 0,
         "sun_2_close": 0
      },
      "payment_options": {
         "cash_only": 0,
         "visa": 0,
         "amex": 0,
         "mastercard": 0,
         "discover": 0
      },
      "restaurant_services": {
         "reserve": 0,
         "walkins": 0,
         "groups": 0,
         "kids": 0,
         "takeout": 0,
         "delivery": 0,
         "catering": 0,
         "waiter": 0,
         "outdoor": 0
      },
      "restaurant_specialties": {
         "breakfast": 0,
         "lunch": 0,
         "dinner": 0,
         "coffee": 0,
         "drinks": 0
      },
      "can_post": true
   }
}
```

I have never received such result. I do not know what `parking` or `restaurant_specialties` are doing here.

However when passing the same post URL but with `www`:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.blog.com/2011/07/04/post-name/
```

I get what there actually should be:

```
{
   "http://www.blog.com/2011/07/04/post-name/": {
      "id": "http://www.blog.com/2011/07/04/post-name/",
      "shares": 4
   }
}
```

Is there something wrong with Facebook? What can I do so that I can keep on saving the Facebook like number to the post meta data as I used to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since id serves as identifying key for your page, it matters whether there is or isn't `www`.

You must use the identical permalink that you used to create the like button, I believe.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. But first - `'http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . get_permalink()` used to give expected results. Second - `echo get_permalink()` returns URL without `www` and I'm afraid I don't know if I can and should add `www` to it. Moreover in both cases: in the button and in the function for saving the count number to post meta data there's all and the same `get_permalink()`. The button shows correct number and the meta data shows null.

Comment: Bump! I won't know how else it should be to resolve your problem without getting my hands on it.

If I were you, I would check out some of their documentations and statuses. (Though, I admit, their support and the giant list of bugs they have can be quite confusing)